# What is the default for AddJsonFile options in configuration under .NET Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, configuration

According to [some wise source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.jsonconfigurationextensions.addjsonfile?view=aspnetcore-2.2), there's a method called *AddJsonFile* for reading in a config file. [One of its signatures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.jsonconfigurationextensions.addjsonfile?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_JsonConfigurationExtensions_AddJsonFile_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfigurationBuilder_Microsoft_Extensions_FileProviders_IFileProvider_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_) allows to specify *optional* and *reloadOnChange*.

```
IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
  .AddJsonFile("config.json", false, false)
  .Build();
```

However, I can't find info on what's the default value for that in case I use a signature without those explicitly specified. I can assume that it's *false*, basing it on the fact that it's the default value of a boolean (i.e. *default(bool)* is *false*).

But I prefer to have stuff explicitly and linkably stated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Refer the source code present at: https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/master/src/Config.Json/JsonConfigurationExtensions.cs

As per this, if you dont provide parameters they are false. Please note below method:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Adds the JSON configuration provider at <paramref name="path"/> to <paramref name="builder"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="builder">The <see cref="IConfigurationBuilder"/> to add to.</param>
        /// <param name="path">Path relative to the base path stored in 
        /// <see cref="IConfigurationBuilder.Properties"/> of <paramref name="builder"/>.</param>
        /// <returns>The <see cref="IConfigurationBuilder"/>.</returns>
        public static IConfigurationBuilder AddJsonFile(this IConfigurationBuilder builder, string path)
        {
            return AddJsonFile(builder, provider: null, path: path, optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);
        }
}
```

As you mentioned earlier in the question, you can use another overload of this method to set reloadOnChange value.  Below is sample code [from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2):

```
public class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);

                config.AddCommandLine(args);
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what got me suspicious. Usually, I prefer not to set explicitly such that already is implicitly defaulted (for the sake of compactness and brevity). However, I've see numerous examples with those two parameters set to false and that got me thinking that, perhaps, those are set to true by default and, hence, require falsifying explicitly. I realize now that it's a case of misleading example copied over and over in numerous blogs. Same goes for the excessively specification of the named parameters. That's not needed and, in my view, confusing.